# jbutton font size change error as "identifier expected"

Tags: java, jbutton

I'm compiling my java code but showing error as `identifier expected`.

```
private JButton AButton = new JButton("A"); 
Font myFont = new Font("Courier", Font.ITALIC,12); 
A.setFont(myFont); // error : identifier expected "
```

Comment: please format your code before posting a question next time. . .

Comment: the error clearly is that `A` isn't an undeclared identifier, since you declared your `JButton` to have the name `AButton` and not `A`. . .

Answer (score 0):

use `AButton` instead of `A`, your line should like:

```
AButton.setFont(myFont);
```